# What is SSL encrypting my web pages if IIS isn't?

Tags: ssl, iis-6, hosting, web-hosting

I have a client who wants to set up SSL on a new directory on their website. They already have one directory using SSL. BUT, when I go into IIS, even the current encrypted directory isn't set up to require SSL. And, when I set either the new or old directory to require SSL it returns and error page stating that I need to call the page over https (which I did), no matter what.

We are not running in a farm. This is a single web server with no load balancing or proxy that I know of. 443 is not blocked. The log files shows a request for the page over 443, but redirects to http.  What could be handling the encryption?

ASP.NET 2.0 APP running on IIS 6.0.

Any help is appreciated.

Thx,
T

Answer (score 0):

Your comment "The log files shows a request for the page over 443, but redirects to http" implies yours pages are being sent over port 80. If this is the case what makes you think your pages are being encryted?

Another thought - are you running any ISAPI extensions such as Helicon?

Comment: On the sever SSL is set up on 443.  The call from the browser was "https://abc.com/dir", but the response was a 302 -> "http://abc.com/dir"

Comment: for some reason it took off the https and the http from the above links.

Comment: Also, no ISAPI extentions are being used.

Comment: Is there actually a certificate installed?

Comment: Also is directory browsing permitted?